# How to start Fragment from onClick

Tags: android, onclick, fragment

I am using recyclerview in my app. I want to start a fragment when click on image view. But i don't know how to. Also i want to put data when starting fragment. I know how to start the activity with below code. But how can i start fragment same way?

Edited Code

```
   FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
   FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.layoutContent, frag);
   ft.commit();
```

Comment: I've edited my code. But as mentioned there, I wouldn't try to replace the fragment from another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments cannot be started, they must be added to a container.
Fragments aren't meant to function on their own, they need an enclosing Activity.
Having the following layout:

```
    [...]
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
    [...]
```

You place the fragment in it like such:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

You pass arguments to the fragment by using Bundle and creating the fragment as follows:

```
TestFragment newFragment = new TestFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Hello world!");
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

This has to be done before the transaction.

For further info refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Note on edited code: you have to call the transaction from inside the Activity the FrameLayout is part of. 
Alternatively use a rather dirty workaround:
In Main:

```
public class Main extends Activity{
  public static Main currentInstance;

  public void onCreate(Bundle boomerang){
    currentInstance = this;
  }
}
```

In the Playlist activity then use `Main.currentInstance.getSupportFragmentManager()` etc.
But I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Okay, I have one more question. I want to start a fragment from playlist activity but the fragment is in main activity. If I use FragmentTransaction, it gives error that "No view found for ID for fragment"

Comment: Could you please post your current code in your question? Is your Fragment in the main set with `public static class NameOfFragment`?

Comment: I have updated the code, the error is due to layoutContent which in mainactivity layout. And I am trying to change it from playlistdetails activity.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start a fragment you need to make use of the fragment manager.

```
YourFragment yourFragmentInstance = YourFragment.newInstance("Hello", 12);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//Fragment is hosted by an activity, and the activity must have a layout
//or a container for the fragment to be nested in, in this case it will be
//a FrameLayout with an id fragment_container
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, yourFragmentInstance);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And you can pass in arguments to your fragment like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    public static YourFragment newInstance(String paramOne, int paramTwo) {
        YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        //set params/arguments for fragment
        b.putString("param_one", paramOne);
        b.putInt("param_two", paramTwo);
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Get the params you passed in
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String paramOne = bundle.getString("param_one");
        String paramTwo = bundle.getInt("param_two");
    }
}
```

Note: I've not tested this code.. This is just an idea :)